# matplotlib: how can I "predraw" an animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-multiprocessing

Currently, my custom animation class's `_draw_frame` function does this:

1. get line data for timestep `n`
2. update data of each line of interest in the axes with `set_data` (lets say for the sake of an example (`ax_line1.set_data(datax, datay`, where `ax_line1, = ax.plot(...)`)
3. make a list of each line that was updated, and set `self._drawn_artists` to that (so in the example if two lines of interest are there, then we update them `self._drawn_artists = [ax_line1, ax_line2]`

Is there a way I can set the data in multiple copies of the line artists before `_draw_frame` is called? Then, all that `_draw_frame` has to do is fetch the predrawn lines, and update the drawn artist list with that.

That means that I set the artist data in parallel, if I have the data already, and thus produce an animation faster? I tried doing `copy.deepcopy` of the artists, but got an error telling me that I cannot do so (`TransformationNode` has to be frozen). What other options do I have?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly - are you saying you basically want to create a bunch of line objects before you start making the animation and then pass a list of them to _draw_frame to indicate which ones to add to a given frame? Do you ever need to undraw lines? Are you using blitting?

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly. I'd need to undraw these lines for the next frame, I suppose, but I am guessing that happens somewhere I am not touching at the moment. I am not using blitting, because I don't know enough about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the data in parallel, I think your best option is to just create all of the line objects that you will need by calling the constructor that many times. Then you can iterate through them and set data as appropriate. If a lot of your lines are supposed to be identical share attributes, you can achieve this with the [update_from](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.update_from) method of matplotlib artists. You could [freeze](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0351/) some of the line objects to allow them to be copied, but then you wouldn't be able to change the data.

That said, when you consider that you'll be needing to undraw lines as well, I'm not sure how much time this will save you. If you have a massive amount of data that you can handle in a very parallel manner, then it might be worth it.

Still, if you really want to speed this up, you should probably use blitting. The basic idea behind blitting is this:

- Start out by drawing any background elements that will be present in all frames.
- All other elements in your animation are represented as drawable objects of some sort (which `lines` conveniently are)
- For every frame, you update any attributes of your drawables that you need to. Then you return a list of everything that you changed an attribute of.
- Matplotlib's `FuncAnimation` function handles the rest with shocking efficiency.

Because all of your operations involve updating lines, this is a pretty ideal scenario in which to use blitting. Matplotlib's documentation on blitting is not incredibly clear, so, if you want more detail, I wrote [this tutorial](http://devosoft.org/making-efficient-animations-in-matplotlib-with-blitting/), which has example code and such.

Comment: You might have noticed already on your own, the link to the [ Blitting Tutorial ] is not working anymore. You might want to kindly update your post with a renewed URL, or repair the broken-link in some other manner. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such help, currently experience headbangs on efficient and fast vector-scene updates, so such helpfull hand is the more appreciated. Wish you endless flow of creativity and limitless sparkles of inspiration for your current and future R&D programmes.